# Browser automation from the browser's JS environment

Tags: javascript, browser-automation

There are about a dozen javascript APIs for doing **DOM/http automation** (for scripts like: `go to this URL then click "login" then type "foo" in username and "bar" in password then click submit`) but all the ones I've seen either expect to run inside Node or worse expect access to some binary like Webkit etc...

Isn't there any library that I can load into my browser's JS environment at runtime (just like I can load Jquery or whatever) that will give me basic automation functionality? (request a url, query the DOM, click buttons, enter form data, etc)

It would be nice if I could watch what's happening while my automation scripts run, but that's not strictly necessary and I have a feeling this might ...it could just use [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) or something.

Comment: @themirror http://docs.seleniumhq.org/ doesn't fit for you?

Comment: yes, it's called greasemonkey on firefox and tampermonkey on chrome.

Comment: @dandavis this does not address the question -- the questions asks for ways that do not involve anything beyond the browser JS environment, which certainly includes binaries like firefox!

Comment: Could you use a testing library like Jasmine? Here's an example of it in use. http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/test/

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall that actually looks pretty close... but I still wonder if there's a package out there that bundles something like Jasmine together with some micro libraries for form filling, button clicking, etc.

Comment: @themirror I definitely wouldn't doubt it! Also wouldn't be surprised if there's a SaaS tool somewhere for this.

Comment: greasemonkey and tampermonkey both run in the browser and allow you to load an external script, just like one loads jquery, except that the script runs automatically and on any site, not just the ones you control. a single line of js run from a userscript can accomplish each of the example tasks like fill an input (inpName.value='fred'), click a button (btnSubmit.click()), or go to a url (location.href='//google.com'). why make it any more complicated?

Comment: @dandavis -- no problem, but this answers a different question than the one that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just run some code in your console?

(jquery example)

```
$('#form #inputElem').val('username');
$('#form #inputElem2').val('password');
$('#form').submit();
```